# Why is Firefox black-boxing my js files

Tags: firefox, console

I'm facing this strange behavior. Mozilla firefox is blocking two of my js files. The debugger says "The Source is black boxed". Its happening with zRSSfeed.js and Wow.js although wow animations are working. Check out the screenshot.

Please let me know how to prevent this on not only my computer but also on everyone else visiting the site.

[Screenshot](http://exploitrip.in/testpad/img/71.jpg)

Check out the rss feed in the footer of this page:
Demo: [Website](http://m.exploitrip.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per what I know from **[This Link](https://divshot.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/ignoring-library-code-while-debugging-in-chrome/)** it cannot be avoided.

and as per below statements from several forums it will not effect your application working.

> In modern web development, we often rely on libraries like jQuery,
>   Ember, or Angular, and 99% of the time we can safely assume that they
>   “just work”. We don’t care about the internal implementation of these
>   libraries: we treat them like a black box. However, a library’s
>   abstraction leaks during debugging sessions when you are forced to
>   step through its stack frames in order to reach your own code. With
>   black boxing, you can tell the debugger to ignore the details of
>   selected sources.

When a source is black boxed:

**Any breakpoints it may have are disabled.
When “Pause on Exceptions” is enabled in the Debugger settings, the debugger won’t pause when an exception is thrown in the black boxed source; instead it will wait until (and if) the stack unwinds to a frame in a source that isn’t black boxed. The debugger will skip through black boxed sources when stepping.**

**[SOURCE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Black_box_a_source)**

Comment: So the reason the jquery is not working on firefox is something else? I've added the link to my website, please have a look.

Comment: @VeeK. What version of firefox you are using? See I just tested in FF v19.0.2 and when I clicked on the RSS icon in footer I just got a pop up which had a URL and a message saying copy this URL to get feeds. Is that what you are expecting to happen in the FF version you are using??

Comment: No not that, look at the "pre-footer". There's an empty column titled "Recent Blog Posts" which is empty. If you look at it in chrome, you'll see the list of blog posts.
P.S. I'm using Firefox 36.0.1

Comment: I don't think its because of that [not sure though] because if you remove that js from blackbox list and then refresh the page [keeping the console open] still the result is same in FF. But I noticed it's coming good in IE and Chrome. That's why I mentioned not sure about this. Actually according to **[this link](https://ffdevtools.uservoice.com/forums/246087-firefox-developer-tools-ideas/suggestions/6640619-maintain-list-of-js-file-for-automatically-blackbo)** this is still under review by FF.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some usefull information for you in this article:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/DevTools/Hacking

It looks like u don't have "black-boxed" class for some of your black-boxed source elements in these js files.

Possibly code like this

```
if (aSource.isBlackBoxed) {
contents.classList.add("black-boxed");
}
```

can help you to fix this

Comment: You might be on to something there. Could you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't the problem of black boxing (I guess). The issue was caused by a code I added in another js file

```
if(localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown'){
    setTimeout(popup, 14000);           
    function popup() {
        $('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
    }
    localStorage.setItem('popState','shown')
}
```

It works perfectly in all other browsers but firefox for some reason is returning an error the the popup function (line 2) is not defined, so I changed it to

```
if(localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown'){
    function popup() {
        $('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
    }
    setTimeout(popup, 14000);
    localStorage.setItem('popState','shown')
}
```

And everything's normal now. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler way.

```html
if(localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown'){
  setTimeout(function(){$('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible')}, 14000);
  localStorage.setItem('popState','shown')
}
```